# Can I get a defined variable for $_SERVER anchor tag, with htacess in PHP?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Firstly I set htaccess, removing php extension, shorting and prettifying the URLs with foreign variables and with languages tags.

The file .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +MultiViews

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php?hl=pt_BR [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php?hl=en [L]

    RewriteRule ^galeria$ album.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^galeria$ album.php?hl=pt_BR [L]
    RewriteRule ^photos$  album.php?hl=en [L]

    # Return 404 if original request is .php
    # RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
    # RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
</IfModule>
```

My website has two languages.

Two languages in PHP:

en.php:

```
define('_album', "Photos Gallery");  
define('_html_lingua', "en");  
define('_url_album', "photos");
```

pt.php:

```
define('_album', "Galeria");  
define('_html_lingua', "pt_BR");  
define('_url_album', "galeria");
```

Now, I added _url_album to an anchor:

```
<li><a class="waves-effect" href="<?php echo _url_album; ?>?hl=<?php echo _html_lingua ?>"><?php echo _album; ?></a></li>
```

It outputs like:

if you switch to English:

```
<li><a class="waves-effect" href="photos?hl=en">Photos Gallery</a></li>
```

if you switch to Portuguese:

```
<li><a class="waves-effect" href="galeria?hl=pt_BR">Galeria</a></li>
```

Then in language picker:

```
<li><a class="waves-effect" href="<?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "album.php?hl=en") { echo _url_album; } ?>?hl=en" name="en"><img alt=""src="imagens/bandeiras/en.svg"> English</a></li>

<li><a class="waves-effect" href="<?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "album.php?hl=pt_BR") { echo _url_album; } ?>?hl=pt_BR" name="pt_BR"><img alt="" src="imagens/bandeiras/pt-br.svg"> Português Brasileiro</a></li>
```

It should be like:

```
<li><a class="waves-effect" href="photos?hl=en" name="en"><img alt=""src="imagens/bandeiras/en.svg"> English</a></li>

<li><a class="waves-effect" href="galeria?hl=pt_BR" name="pt_BR"><img alt="" src="imagens/bandeiras/pt-br.svg"> Português Brasileiro</a></li>
```

But at album page, in English, at the language picker, if you hover Portuguese without clicking, it appears as "`photos?hl=pt_BR`" instead of "`galeria?hl=pt_BR`". In Portuguese, if you hover English, it appears as "`galeria?php=en`". I found it ugly.

I want to do like: In Portuguese, if you hover English, I want it to appear as "`photos?hl=en`" at the language picker. And so!

Comment: Instead of using defines, use a two-level array, something like `$languages = array(`album` => array => ('en' => 'Photos Gallery', 'pt' => 'Galeria')...)` and access it as `$languages['album']['en']`. Also don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` anytime you include text in HTML, otherwise you'll end up with issues when you have special characters in your text.

Comment: Why would you want to change the working of the internal, technical identifiers in your URLs? Sure, possible, but _why_? That adds complexity  without offering any benefit. Those identifiers have technical meaning only, they should not get translated.

Comment: @jcaron, maybe your code is wrong. Please, correct a bit.

Comment: @arkascha, imagine an English-speaking visitor writing the full URL `.../galeria.php?jl=en`. He doesn't know what the word galeria is. He would have facility to write quickly like `.../photos?hl=en` or just `.../photos`.

Comment: Why should a visitor of your site have to write a URL? That makes no sense...

Comment: Because the default language of the home page always is Portuguese, every time the visitor has to change the language at the language picker.

Comment: Better keeping names of URL pages untranslated?

Comment: Translating urls could help for SEO purposes. It’s probably not as important as some male it to be, but it can have an influence. In any case, even if not for URL, it can make sense to be able to access translation strings from languages other than he current one.

Comment: @GustavoReis the quotes got mangled a bit, but you should be able to extrapolate from that, shouldn’t you?